# Get name of formfield which calls macro on entry

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a few formfield objects, that calls a macro on entry.

How do I get the name of the formfield which called the macro? Something like application.caller but for Word.

Comment: This has been asked and answered previously. See [How to change the text of a form field text box on entry of that text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878989/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-form-field-text-box-on-entry-of-that-text-box)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean a "Legacy Form Field" in the document itself, if you have set the "Run macro on entry" in the properties of the Form Field to a suitable Sub, you can use code like the following:

```
If Selection.FormFields.Count = 1 Then
  ' This deals with dropdown etc. but not FORMTEXT fields
  Debug.Print Selection.FormFields(1).Name
ElseIf Selection.FormFields.Count = 0 And Selection.Bookmarks.Count > 0 Then
  Debug.Print Selection.Bookmarks(Selection.Bookmarks.Count).Name
End If
```

A FormField does not actually have to have a name, in which case it will not have a Bookmark, so you may need to allow for that.

If you mean some other type of field such as a VBA UserForm field, Content Control or ActiveX field in the document, please modify your question to make that clear.